# End NodeJS program using streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have a small program that is running an ETL pipeline on some XML data. I'm using `pump` ([package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pump)) to combine a `Readable`, `Duplex`, and `Writeable` streams. I'm getting the final 'done' callback, but the program doesn't exit. Is the only way to handle this to call `process.exit(0)`?

Here's the code snippet:

```
pump(
    fileStream,
    parser,
    inserter,
    (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** Just to close the loop, what @FakeFootball suggested does the trick:

```
pump(
        fileStream,
        parser,
        inserter,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                parser.destroy();
                inserter.destroy();
                fileStream.destroy();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, my guess is you aren't closing/destroying any of your streams so they are still active. Node won't close as it is still listening for potential actions on those streams. See the example in the usage section of the pump documentation for how they close the stream and it destroys the rest of them. [Pump usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pump#usage)

Comment: Yeah so that's my question. Is there a 'proper' way to signal that the streams are done without calling `destroy`? Ideally I'd like the `end` event from the file stream to trigger an end on the parser and then an end on the db handler. Manually calling `destroy` is more or less the same as calling `process.exit()` for my purposes.

Comment: Well process.exit will in effect destroy your stream, you want to handle it elegantly as there may be housekeeping (e.g closing database connections) that happens when you destroy the streams in your code and may not happen if you kill the program with process.exit. In your case, I would just add the destroy statements in the finished callback along side the console.log("done").